# Should we use the LAN IP or the public IP for bind settings such as A records, etc.?

Tags: ip, domain, bind

I'm a newcomer to working with bind, and a while ago, I purchased a static IP from an ISP. I used bind to bring up a domain, and now it's working without any issues.

For example: the LAN network IP for my service is 192.168.1.101, and the IP I purchased from the ISP is 120.4.5.6. The domain name, for instance, is example.com. Following the tutorial on  [digitalocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-bind-as-a-private-network-dns-server-on-ubuntu-14-04) , I set up A records and zones with the local LAN IP. However, when I pinged it, it returned the local IP, so I could only access the domains from within the LAN. Why did this happen? Instead of the LAN IP, I used the publicly purchased IP and modified the A records in bind accordingly, and now everything is okay! However, it seems incorrect to me because, based on what I know:

When you enter a domain address (like example.com):
First, it checks with the "." to see if it recognizes com or not.
Then, it queries the DNS service related to com to see if it recognizes example or not.
Finally, an IP (120.4.5.6) is returned for example.com. In that case, why, when I set my own LAN IP (192.168.1.101) in bind for A records, I could only access the domain from the internal network, and why did the ping command return the LAN IP (192.168.1.101) instead of the public IP (120.4.5.6)?

I believe that when the DNS provider returns my public IP, the client should know what my IP is. When it is sent to my system, we use bind to configure A records and internal LAN network settings to specify the NS, primary server, and support. If I have misunderstood anything, I would appreciate it if you could let me know.

Comment: You should probably read up on how DNS works and what role it has. It's broadly speaking a directory service, not a routing service.

Comment: `I used bind to bring up a domain, and now it's working without any issues.` ... `I set up A records and zones with the local LAN IP. However, when I pinged it, it returned the local IP, so I could only access the domains from within the internal LAN. Why did this happen?` no "issues" though, right?

Answer (score 0):

With bind you can set up a "split horizon" so that local/LAN queries to your local DNS server instance receive LAN addresses, and queries  originating outside your LAN receive the public IP addresses

Comment: So, do we use bind to specify some nodes in our local network that we have defined in the settings? So that when an external request comes in, it is responded to based on our bind settings?

Answer (score 0):

To make your bind dns publicly available you need to make sure the domain points to your dns server. That would be done by modify the domain and pointing the nameserver to your bind dns server.
Your ISP probably needs to change that for the domains you desire. Then you need to make sure your bind server is reachable on port 53 from the internet. I would not publish your internal ips to the internet so you need to create a split zone which has a public part and internal part. The public zone has records for the public ips your services run on, and the internal one for the internal network. I challenge you to figure out how to create a split zone in bind

Basically it resolved internal records because your bind dns server only knows the internal ips and that's the first one which is queried.
Another option would be to add a resolver to the public dns server of your ISP or something like opendns, with the resolver in bind, if bind can't find a record in your internal zone it queries the public dns hierarchy